# Table of contents in Antenna house - CSS formatting issue

Tags: html, css, antenna-house

**I have a table of contents that should be displayed as below (this was the output I had using Antenna House (trial version) 6.3.**

[image: Previous output]

**(The page numbers should start a set distance from the left hand side of the page.)**

**Having recently upgraded to AH 6.6 the output is now incorrect; during formatting I get:**

[image: Formatting]

**Then finally:**

[image: New output]

**(Sorry about the bold text)**

It seems that the initial 0's change the alignment. The TOC is part of the introduction page, which I think is the reason for it not having the 0's to begin with.

The code I currently have for this is:

```
li[class*='tab-']{
    width: attr(data-tab);
}
li[class*='tab-']::before{
    padding-left: calc(1em * attr(data-cptlv));
}
li[class*='tab-']::after{
    content: '(' attr(data-dict-pgct) ' ' target-counter(attr(data-ref),page) ')';      
    float: right;
}
```

For this TOC the attributes data-tab and data-dict-page are the same for all list items (40% and 'page' repectively). See HTML below:

```
<p class="">For this document the simplified Table of Contents looks like this:</p>
<ul class="tab-40">
  <li class="tab-40" data-cptlv="1" data-chptno="1" data-dict-pgct="page"
      data-xmlno="X00355088"
      data-ref="#X00355088"
      data-tab="40%">
     <a href="#X00355088" class="tab-40" title="Introduction"/>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-40" data-cptlv="1" data-chptno="2" data-dict-pgct="page"
      data-xmlno="X00355092"
      data-ref="#X00355092"
      data-tab="40%">
     <a href="#X00355092" class="tab-40" title="Preparation"/>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-40" data-cptlv="1" data-chptno="3" data-dict-pgct="page"
      data-xmlno="X00355111"
      data-ref="#X00355111"
      data-tab="40%">
     <a href="#X00355111" class="tab-40" title="Tasks"/>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-40" data-cptlv="1" data-chptno="4" data-dict-pgct="page"
      data-xmlno="X00355100"
      data-ref="#X00355100"
      data-tab="40%">
     <a href="#X00355100" class="tab-40" title="Finalization"/>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-40" data-cptlv="1" data-chptno="5" data-dict-pgct="page"
      data-xmlno="X00355103"
      data-ref="#X00355103"
      data-tab="40%">
     <a href="#X00355103" class="tab-40" title="Reference documents"/>
  </li>
  <li class="tab-40" data-cptlv="1" data-chptno="6" data-dict-pgct="page"
      data-xmlno="X00355389"
      data-ref="#X00355389"
      data-tab="40%">
     <a href="#X00355389" class="tab-40" title="Table of Contents"/>
  </li>
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Sorry, added :)

Comment: Why not just give your after a fixed width that is larger than the longest bit of text, that way all the pages will line up

Comment: The HTML is an XSL output so I don't know what the longest piece of text will be in advance. 

I could count the characters for each list item using XSL, then calculate the width from the max value. I was hoping there would be an easier option but that will probably have to be it.

Comment: can't be that many pages - surely (page 9999) should probably cover the longest?  would anyone be reading a longer document?!

Comment: Sorry I thought you meant the title. Yes, that seems much simpler, thanks!

Comment: Has this been solved?

Comment: FYI, the '000' are from `-ah-assumed-page-number` (https://www.antenna.co.jp/AHF/help/en/ahf-ext.html#axf.assumed-page-number). AH Formatter defaults to using a three-digit place-holder for page number references. This leads to smaller changes (particularly in running text) compared to the page number reference having zero width until the page number is known. If you know that page numbers won't reach 100, you can set `-ah-assumed-page-number` to `99` (or any two-digit number, although '11' tends to be narrow) so that the initial formatting is more accurate.